# Powershell : Copy-item "[...]\*" : Error due to space in path

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Bonjour Mesdames, Messieurs,

I wrote a script in powershell to save a folder content.
Firts version of script worked well.

But, I change some path, and created some folder with spaces in the name.
Now, my script crash :-(

I have this error, a lot of time during script execution :
(in french , sorry)

```
Copy-Item : Impossible de trouver une partie du chemin d'accès 'C:\Users\lfrria3\Desktop\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Développements\Developpements
LabView\Ressources\Donnees\Librairies\TestsAutomatiques\Programmes\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Fonctions\Step\TestsNonDeterministes\Fonctions Temps Non Déterministe\Cas
TestNumeric\ConfigurationPasTestNumeric.vi'.
Au caractère C:\Users\lfrria3\Desktop\SAVTestsAutomatiques.ps1:212 : 13
+             Copy-Item -Path "$path" -Destination $CheminRepertoireSAV ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (ConfigurationPasTestNumeric.vi:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Impossible de trouver une partie du chemin d'accès = Unable to found a part of path

I think it's due to spaces in pathes (not sure).

The code lines are :

```
$path='C:\Users\lfrria3\Desktop\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Développements\Developpements LabView\Ressources\Donnees\Librairies\TestsAutomatiques\*'
Copy-Item -Path "$path" -Destination $CheminRepertoireSAV -Recurse
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: The problem is likely not spaces, but that your ultimate path exceeds 260 characters in length -- the well-known and vexing `MAX_PATH` limitation of Windows. There are workarounds for it, but by far the least problematic one is shortening the path yourself.

Comment: are you always looking for the content of the folder "TestsAutomatiques" or are you looking for all the files in the last folder?

Comment: I created the same scenario and it works with the same code...`$path='C:\Test\lfrria3\Desktop\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Développements\Developpements LabView\Ressources\Donnees\Librairies\TestsAutomatiques\*'
$destination="C:\Test2"

Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $Destination -Recurse`

Comment: Could you please create testfolders and test it outside `C:\Users`? You can use my code to generate the folders fast: `$path='C:\Test\lfrria3\Desktop\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Développements\Developpements LabView\Ressources\Donnees\Librairies\TestsAutomatiques\'
$destination="C:\Test2"


New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path,$destination`

Comment: Jeroen : Bingo :-)
I moved my directory '[...]\Donnees\  :
- from : C:\Users\lfrria3\Desktop\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Développements\Developpements LabView\Ressources\Donnees\
- to : C:\Users\lfrria3\Desktop\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Donnees\

Thank you a lot , I could not find alone the solution

Adis1102, thank you too for your help. I assume it works for you because your directory '[...]\TestsAutomatiques\' is empty.

Comment: @Alexandre.R I dont understand, what do you mean by "Bingo"? Is it a rights issue or do you mean the test I asked you for was successful?

Comment: @Adis1102 : I was editing my answer, sorry ( I'm new on StackOverFlow, I didn't know that "enter" send messages ...

Comment: Ok, but what did you do know differently?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question.
I move folders, in order to reduce the string of path (in $path) :
`$path='C:\Users\lfrria3\Desktop\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Donnees\Librairies\TestsAutomatiques\*'
# And no more :
#$path='C:\Users\lfrria3\Desktop\Projet TestsAutomatiques\Développements\Developpements LabView\Ressources\Donnees\Librairies\TestsAutomatiques\*'

Copy-Item -Path "$path" -Destination $CheminRepertoireSAV -Recurse`

Because it concerns software programmation, I need an environnement  wich is in "[...]\Donnees\".
I save only my folder "TestsAutomatiques"